# Meteor: Angular2 VS Blaze confusion

Tags: meteor, angular, meteor-blaze, angular-meteor

I was enthusiast using Angular2 with Meteor, so I started a project with ng2 and Meteor. But more and more I am asking questions like:

- Is ng2 deprecated router the way to go ?
- What is the purpose to use ngForm validation if I use collection2 and autoform to do most of my form validation.
- What are the benefits of ng2 architecture vs Blaze ?

So at the end, I am not even sure of why I am using ng2. There is not that much recent and relevant discussions on the topic. Is that the question that is already answered, obvious or just not so relevant ?

**What are the pros/cons of using Angular 2 versus using Blaze ?**

Blaze was raised with Meteor and is probably linked to his success. And ng2 could be as famous as ng1.

**To be used in serious projects, which one is going to be 'more maintained and last longer' ?**

Regards

PS: Also looking at https://builtwithmeteor.com, Blaze appears to be used more.

Comment: Blaze is used more because it was the only templating system in Meteor for a long time. Angular and React started making appearances late 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular 2 router is deprecated but it's still the only router available to use at the moment. 
In the future versions of Angular 2, a new router will be available. 
So right now- the deprecated router should be used, and I think that it has all the features that you need from a Router.

You can choose to do the validations of the fields as you like. 
Personally, I think that validation should occur in both client and server, so Angular 2 take care of the validations that needed to check in the UI and give feedback in the UI, and the Meteor validations should occur in server side and validate things like duplicates, data logic and such, along with fields validations that done by SimpleSchema.

I think that Angular 2 at the moment provides a better solution for client side development - much of it is because of the decorators that in use, the code is much clearer and easy to understand.
Also, Angular 2 is more that UI binding (which Blaze is...) and give you Dependency Injection, Router, Services and more features that usually required in the UI (in Blaze you need to use external packages for each one of these features).

Keep in mind that few months ago, Meteor team declared that UI developers should consider using another client side framework, and consider migrating from Blaze (they recommended Angular 2 / Angular with angular-meteor.com or React).

If you already have Blaze application, I think that you should consider migrating to Angular 2.

The Angular2-Meteor (www.angular-meteor.com) team is working right now on a full step-by-step tutorial for coexistence and migrating Blaze application to Angular 2.